# Difference Between GNOME on Red Hat and Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

I am learning RHCE 6.0 course.

My questions are:

1. Can I learn it on Ubuntu? (Till now I am able to work, but in future am I supposed to install Red Hat?)
2. What is the difference between GNOME on Red Hat and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Red Hat in VirtualBox if you don't want to install it as a normal operating system installation. A basic vanilla installation of Red Hat in VirtualBox should be enough for what you are trying to do. GNOME on Ubuntu is similar in almost all respects to GNOME on other Linux distributions generally.

Since the course you're taking is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, you will have an easier time with the course if you have the installation iso for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. If you don't have an RHEL 6 iso, then try to install as close a match as you can to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 ships with the GNOME 2 desktop environment which is no longer provided in the repositories of the current versions of Ubuntu Desktop. In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, GNOME 3 is the default desktop environment. GNOME 3 is the version of the GNOME desktop environment that is in the repositories of the current Ubuntu Desktop releases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting RHEL/CentOS 6, they're using GNOME2, that is, the GNOME used on Ubuntu 10.04. So, there's a huge difference in terms of GNOME on Ubuntu 12.04/14.04 with that on RHEL/CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would say that this is not a good idea. Although most basic commands are very similar (or even the same) on Ubuntu and Red Hat, advanced system administration stuff (in terms of tools and procedures) is very different. 
In case you want to practice on a "free" version of Red Hat, I suggest you take a look at CentOS (http://centos.org/).

2) GNOME is a graphical interface for Linux, and is the default for Red Hat and Ubuntu GNOME. Apart from some minor differences, I think both distributions are very similar in this regard.